# How to filter DataTime field by hour in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have Django 1.8 and Python 2.7, I need to get orders made per hour

the field is DateTimeField

```
close_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I do the simple loop:

```
for hour in xrange(0, 24):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(close_date__hour=hour)
```

but it does not filter.

Comment: What is your expected result? Can you describe that too?

Comment: need to aggregate hourly sum of order sales

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`Order.objects.filter(close_date__regex = 'HH:00')` or `(close_date__contains = 'HH:00')`

As perhaps django 1.8 only support year, month, day, week_day.

Comment: I can't use it as it saved and compares with UTC timezone, I need my current timezone

Comment: You can set your desired time zone in settings. py where the default value is UTC.